# How do I scrape a site with phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape a site and grab an iTunes promo code. After a bit of experimentation, I found that I could get the code quite easily with a JavaScript console: http://cl.ly/image/3U1K2a2b1f36/console.png

Shortly thereafter, I tried the following with PhantomJS:

```
 var page = require('webpage').create();
 page.open('http://www.air1.com/music/free-songs.aspx', function () {
     code = page.evaluate(function() {
         __doPostBack('ctl00$cphRight1$itunesPromo$lbGetDownloadCode','');
         return document.getElementById('ctl00_cphRight1_itunesPromo_lblItunesCodes').innerText;
     });

     console.log('Code: ' + code);
     phantom.exit();
 });
```

It didn't work like I thought it would–`code` is returned empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The popup is probably not in the DOM between the call to load it and the call to grab the innerText. Try pausing in between.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.air1.com/music/free-songs.aspx', function (status) {

  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('error');
    phantom.exit();
    return;
  }

  page.evaluate(function() {
    __doPostBack('ctl00$cphRight1$itunesPromo$lbGetDownloadCode','');
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
   var code = page.evaluate(function() {
     return document.getElementById('ctl00_cphRight1_itunesPromo_lblItunesCodes').innerText;
   });
   console.log('code = ' + code);
   phantom.exit();
  }, 1000);
});
```